# Track monthly payments database structure

Tags: php, mysql, database, payment

So I need to track user's monthly payments.

I have a table for the users with all their info.

I'm guessing I'll need another table with all the months since 2010.

I don't know, how is this done? it would also need to add new months as time passes...

I don't really need help with code, just the database structure.

Comment: you need to get grip of the basics of mysql http://tizag.com is a good start to learn

Comment: That tizag website is awful, and that's an understatement. Please, don't try to "learn" anything from "I want advertisement money and I'll stick all random tutorials there" types of websites like tizag or w3schools one.

Answer (score 6):

you need another table for PAYMENT

something like

```
PAYMENT
-------------
payment_id
amount
payment_date
user_id
```

Comment: Okay, I don't know why I didn't think of that... thanks a lot.

Comment: It often happens that people can't see the forest because of the trees :)